# Socialengine cloud changing background color

Tags: socialengine

I am wondering whether anyone knows how to change the background color of header, body and footer?

Most of the posts were for social engine PHP. Any has a ready made CSS script I could use for that purpose?

It would be great if there is a website with a lot of premade CSS script that I could use for social engine cloud.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task is easy but you need some CSS skills to keep your site good looking after such editing :) Use Theme editor in the admin area (/admin/themes?file=theme.css), there are all you need for this task. Look for .layout_page_footer, #global_wrapper, .layout_page_footer (or #global_footer) CSS definition and edit it. Or add any custom CSS to the end.